# Using observeOn and subscribeOn to solve my app freezing issue

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, rx-swift, moya

I am encountering a lot of my users complaining about their app freezing, and I suspect it is due to the network requests.

It has been hard to reproduce tho, but my solution has been to add a subscribeOn and observeOn to my custom mapArray function, which is chained after the moya request but before any ui usage.

Questions:

- does this sequence of calling subscribeOn and observeOn make sense as an approach to solve the freezing issue?
- it feels weird to be calling subscribeOn *after* the function to call, but i do not want to wrap my request in yet another dispatch block

Overall, i am pretty confused by thread switching in Moya and Alamofire, and hoping someone can shine some light:

PS: I have read up the [issue in moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/423) discussing this, and it mentions that alamofire does the network call on the main thread, which is also confusing to me

PS2: this solution is also based on this [blog post](http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/ios/rxswift-examples-4-multithreading/), but my question, besides the above ones, is why it might advocate for running the network call on a background thread when it does not appear to be the case for the Moya guys.

```
 // How the network call is 
 func load() -> Observable<Void> {
    let apiProvider: RxMoyaProvider()
    return apiProvider.request(.GetFeed(page: 1))
      .mapArray(Question.self, keyPath: "questions")
      .doOnNext { questions, pagination in
        // updates the results to a variable, which is bound to the UI
        self.pagination = pagination
        self.data.value = questions
      }
      .flatMapLatest { _ in
        Observable.just()
      }
  }

 // My observable extension, a function to map responses to a 
extension ObservableType where E == Response {

  func mapObject<T: Mappable>(type: T.Type, keyPath: String) -> Observable<T> {
    return
      // this makes sure that the beginning of the call is made on the background thread. but it can be changed later, so we need an observe on later on
      subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(globalConcurrentQueueQOS: .Background))
      .doOnError(networkFailureCallback)
      .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
      .handleUnauthorizedRequest()
        // this makes sure that the mapping happens on a background thread as well
      .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(globalConcurrentQueueQOS: .Background))
      .flatMap { response -> Observable<T> in
        return Observable.just(try response.mapObject(T.self, keyPath: keyPath))
      }
  }
}


// In my viewController
dataAccessor.load()
  .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
  .subscribe { error in
    // do actions
  }
  .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```